# Scrapy - How save the json file in S3 and local file system - at same time

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, scrapy

I'm already have my settings set to save the `json` in a `S3` bucket. But I want to save also in my local machine, if this is possible.

I tried the config below, but `Scrapy` save only in the local machine.

```
FEED_URI = 's3://bucket/scraped/file.jl'
FEED_URI = 'file:///tmp/file.jl'
```

I dont understand very well the settings explained by the `Scrapy` docs [here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#topics-feed-storage-backends)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scrapy's feed exports extension doesn't support sending items to two places at the time.

`FEED_URI` in your settings is just a Python variable, so the reason it's only saving in your local machine is because it's being overwritten the second time.

You can work around that by using FEED_URI to send items to S3 and writing a pipeline that saves your items locally.

Comment: Hi Elias! Tks! Please, do you have a pipeline example for this purpose?

Comment: I don't, but if you try to do one I can help you with it.